# How to get last row from column in a specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that opens an excel spreadsheet and gets the last empty row in that column. The problem I am having is that I have two tables created in my excel spreadsheet. I want to be able to only select the range of B7:B94 for column B  as I have data that represents another table starting at B:101
Here is my code so far...

```
Const xlUp = -4162

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
    .Visible = False
    Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open("M:\Shared Documents\Job Cost Analysis\Hi-Tech BPO\Logs\" & currentMonth & "-Summary Hi Tech BPO.xlsx", , False)
    Set ws = .Worksheets(sheetName) 

Dim LR
 '''''''''''Here is where I want to select the range of B7:B94''''''''''''''
LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("B" & LR + 1).Value = RIGHT(client_id,LEN(client_id)-7) 

End With

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlWB.SaveAs ("M:\Shared Documents\Job Cost Analysis\Hi-Tech BPO\Logs\" & currentMonth & "-Summary Hi Tech BPO.xlsx")
xlWB.Close
xlApp.Quit
```

Comment: Are those actual ListObject (aka *structured*) tables or just blocks of data?

Comment: and `LR = .Range("B101").End(xlUp).Row` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unstructured blocks of data,

```
LR = .Range("B100").End(xlUp).Row
```

For true [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx) (aka [structured](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E)) tables,

```
LR = .Range("B100").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row
```

The latter assumes that the table is not 'full'. A check to ensure LR is not 7 should be made.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
.Range("B7").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Row
```